# Different ways of dynamically allocate 2D array with variable lengths

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

I searched a lot how to allocate dynamic 2D array of variable lengths(row and col)
I found these two ways:

1st one:

```
int (*array) [M] = new int[N][M];
```

2nd one:

```
int ** array = new int[row];
for(int i =0; i<width;i++){
   array[i] = new array[col];
}
```

I got confused and don't know what is the difference and which is better.

Comment: Yes these are array of pointers to pointers, but I want to know what are the difference between both?

Comment: Use `std::array<std::array<your_Type_here>>`. that's if your 2D array is of fixed size and will never grow or shrink. use `std::vector<std::vector<...>>` otherwise. For the difference, the first `array` in your code is a pointer to `N` arrays of arrays which contain `M` integers. The second `array` is a pointer to `N` arrays that contains pointers to integer pointer, which afterward you can NEWque arrays of different sizes. Basically the first is a fixed size 2D array, the second is a fixed size array in `row` term, but can have columns of different sizes.

Comment: i would suggest to use the 2nd one whenever you can. It's easier to read and understand